# Angular Radio Buttons Form Validation

Tags: angularjs, json, validation, radio-button

I'm generating a group of radio buttons options from a JSON object which is requested when another radio button is selected. This works as expected but the form validation is not working correctly since the form only becomes valid if all the options in the radio button group are first clicked.

My mark-up for the radio button:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="option in options" class="radio">
     <label>
          <input type="radio" name="decline_type_id" ng-model="decline_type_id" value="{{option.id}}" ng-required="!decline_type_id" />
          <strong>{{option.name}}</strong>
     </label>
</div>
```

Here is my plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/B7KgUt4GMrnSATYIQuN5?p=preview

The same mark-up without the loop works as expected, so I don't understand what it is about the loop used to generate the list that is breaking the validation of the form until all options are selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Angular scoping issue. The ng-model inside the ng-repeat is using a child scope.

The `ng-model="decline_type_id"` was unique for each iteration of the loop. So ng-required check was for each unique model.

You can make use of $parent scope to do the ng-required checking on a shared variable instead.

`<input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.decline_type_id" value="{{option.id}}" ng-required="!$parent.decline_type_id" />`